# Why are some of the photos from my iphone is rotated when I display it on the computer?

Tags: ios, image-processing

I use some test images for my iphone app, and the app mysterious breaks when it shouldn't. I finally opened up the photo with an image viewer and noticed that the photos are rotated. I did not expect this at all.

How do I know an image is rotated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImage has an `imageOrientation` property. That returns the orientation defined in the image's metadata or `UIImageOrientationUp` as a default.

But really, if your app breaks because of the orientation, you might be doing some things in a way you shouldn't do.. (can't remember how often i got EXEC_BAD_ACCESS oO) i suggest running leaks / zombie instruments with the xcode profiling feature.